# Cuda installation to Gentoo

Tags: linux, gentoo, cuda, nvidia-quadro

I desperate to install dev-util/nvidia-cuda-sdk to my Gentoo system (3.12.30-gentoo kernel) for programming and for rendering with blender 2.72b

I have a Nvidia Quadro FX 3700 graphic card using the 173.14.39 nvidia-driver (Legacy). Are there any solution not involving buying a new video card?

Comment: Because you have also registered at Ask Ubuntu, I'll mention that Ubuntu 14.04 and beyond has all the CUDA good stuff in their repos, but you have to have a graphics card capable of using the nvidia-331 driver or newer. NVIDIA Graphics cards with 1GB built-in memory are very cheap, you would be surprised at how cheap, and a 1GB NVIDIA graphics card rocks with CUDA and Blender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The driver you are trying to install is too old (between cuda 1.1 and 2.0).

Your gpu is compute capability 1.1. It isn't suported by newest cuda driver (the driver that comes with cuda 7.0), but you can install a slight older toolkit like cuda 5.0 with its driver or a slightly newer (340.76 for example).